# Alternate phrase for "be damned" to avoid profanity

Tags: idioms, offensive-language, synonyms

How could you rephrase something like this usage of "be damned" to avoid profanity, but without losing the emphasis conveyed by the idiom itself?

> I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, moderators be damned!

(Just kidding moderators, I love you!)

Comment: I suspect you can't. That's why profanity has impact.

Comment: "Never mind the moderators!" perhaps

Comment: @medica Stuff the moderators?

Comment: @Araucaria - I think that actually works!

Answer (score 3):

"Be damned" here indicates strong unconcern about the thing being (possibly) damned. "Let them be damned, I'm doing it anyway", etc. Regardless of the fate of X, even if X should be subjected to the worst possible fate, you will continue with your course of action. Thus, there are various ways to restate the entire phrase:

> I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, regardless of the consequences!

or

> ... despite the moderators!

or even

> ... and let the moderators do what they will.

---

If those aren't quite emphatic enough, you could always use a non-word:

> ... irregardless of the moderators and their draconian rules!

Using double negation for emphasis is surprisingly common in colloquial English, despite the keepers of the language repeatedly telling us how illogical it is. You *will* tick people off, but maybe that's a desirable outcome.

Comment: Not "irregardless," please. *Regardless* already means "without regard"; you don't need the *ir-* prefix as well.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you, that was an excellent demonstration of my point.

Comment: No, I wrote that comment as a user, regardless of a diamond. I *could* remove your response if I felt draconian, but I don't.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Mmm, not quite the point I had in mind, but I guess that works too?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, moderators be damned!

For a non-overtly profane rephrasing you could have:

> Stuff the moderators!  I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, {moderators or {no moderators / not}} / {whether the moderators like it or not}!"

Comment: Nice answer but difficult to read ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria - Thanks for the feedback. I'd like to be able to improve the readability of my response by using differently-coloured text for the various phrasing options, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to an available editing tool.

Answer (score 1):

As many people recognize this from the Bible, I wouldn't sanitize it unless it's being used in elementary school materials. It meant someone condemned (by God) and sent to Hell, Hades or eternal destruction and was meant to startle.

I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, moderators go to Hades.

or

I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, and moderators, you're condemned to silence.

or

I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, and moderators, your opinions are censured.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in a single word, perhaps "moderators *notwithstanding*"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "the end justifies the means". It means almost the exact same thing, while still having a poetic and emphatic sound to it.

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for this answer, and decided to go with:
I'm going to ask this question on StackExchange, and all the moderators, can worry about themselves.
I believe the phrase "be damned" denotes that I "have no care/concern/love for", "in spite of any harm that may befall them".

Comment: Hi Tim! While I agree that a good solution would switch out "be damned" for an equivalent phrase, your version doesn't strongly convey the idea of doing something regardless of what the moderators think. (See the answer above that has "regardless of the consequences," which sums up this aspect of "moderators be damned!") Also, the second comma shouldn't be there because it is separating the subject ("all the moderators") from the verb ("can worry")